# Divide numbers in 2 multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have 2 sets of multidimensional array ($profit & $sales). I want to divide the numbers in 2 multidimensional array to get the % of margin **(using this formula: $profit/$sales*100)**

```
$profit= array(
    0 => array(
        "no"=> "1",
        "value"=>"10"
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "no"=> "2",
        "value"=>"15"
    )
);

$sales= array(
    0 => array(
        "no"=> "1",
        "value"=>"100"
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "no"=> "2",
        "value"=>"200"
    )
);
```

This is the expected output:

```
$margin= array(
    0 => array(
        "no"=> "1",
        "value"=>"10"
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "no"=> "2",
        "value"=>"7.5"
    )
);
```

I have done some search with no luck still, below is the function that I'm using, it is not working:

```
function ArrayDivide($arrayList = [])
{

    $m = [];
    $no_details = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($arrayList as $arrayItem) {
        foreach ($arrayItem as $subArray) {
            if (isset($no_details[$subArray['x']])) {//if no is exist
                $m[$no_details[$subArray['x']]]['y'] =  $m[$no_details[$subArray['x']]]['y'] /$subArray['y']*100;
            } else {
                $no_details[$subArray['x']] = $i;
                $m[$i] = ["x"=>$subArray['x'], "y"=>"0"];
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }    
    return $m;

}
```

How you done similar function before? Where should I fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? If I understood your question correctly.

```
function getMargin($profit, $sales){

    $margin = [];

    foreach($profit as $key => $val){

        $no = $val['no'];
        $value = $val['value'];

        if(isset($sales[$key]) && $sales[$key]['no'] == $no){

            $res = ($value/$sales[$key]['value'])*100;

            $margin[$key]['no'] = $no;
            $margin[$key]['val'] = $res;

        }


    }

    return $margin;

}


var_dump(getMargin($profit, $sales));
```

Comment: i wish to get the profit margin using this formula: $profit/$sales*100..

Answer (score 0):

Use "Sourcey86" code and replace:

`$res = $value / $no;`

to

`$res = $value/$sales[$key]['value']*100;`

(I don't have enough points to add a comment on his post :D )